# Dependancy resolving with Bazel

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

In code that I'm working, I see following Bazel dependency.

```
'//software/abc/def/ghi/startup:hhLib',
```

but in `startup/BUILD` file I don't see **hhlib** target.
Is this a default target in Bazel or I need to create it manually.

Further I see dependent entries like `*:iflib` too.

Can someone tell more about `hhlib` and `iflib` in Bazel

Comment: May be any alias for those targets?

Comment: No, bzl itself would not be adding dependencies on `hhlib` or `iflib` targets. This comes from build tree description that you are dealing with. How exactly is impossible to deduce from the information provided atm.

Answer (score 0):

The stanzas in BUILD files can either be:

- the instantiation of bazel rules (either builtin rules included in bazel, or extensions defined by Starlark)
- macro calls, which are Starlark functions that themselves instantiate one or more bazel rules

Macros are often written to look like rules (having `name`, `deps`, attributes, etc.) but may instantiate rules with arbitrary names in their implementation. Unfortunately, this can make things confusing for users, who see bazel targets that they can't find a corresponding stanza for in the BUILD file.

My first inclination is that `startup/BUILD` contains such a macro; you could check by running `bazel query --output=BUILD '//software/abc/def/ghi/startup:*'`; this will generate a BUILD file after macro resolution. If you do see the target you're looking for, there will also be comments describing the macros called to generate that target.